# ReactJS - What are the pros and cons of managing context outside of the component tree?

Tags: reactjs

In a React (Native) application, consider a util file such as:

```
let apples = 0;

export function addApple() {
    apples++;
}

export function getApples() {
    return apples;
}
```

Is it okay to store the state of apples this way such that components can modify it like:

```
import { addApple } from "./myUtil";

export function AddAppleButton {
    return <button onClick={addApples} />
}
```

And non-React code can use it like:

```
import { addApple } from "./myUtil";

export function addMultipleApples(numberOfApples) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfApples; i++) {
        addApple();
    }
}
```

What are the pros and cons of managing context this way?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, it won't work. Since `apples` is not managed by react state, when it changes, React will not trigger a re-render so the value will not update on screens that read from it. It may *accidentally* look like it's working if a re-render happens for some other reason, React will pick up the new value -- but this would be extremely fragile and inevitably lead to indeterminate states and race conditions you don't want to exist.

For what you need to do, it would make more sense to build a store container (like a class) and put this in the React state, then add methods to that store such that its values can be read and written from the outside. The store would need to inform components listening to it the value changed, via a subscription mechanism or similar. This is a fairly complex thing to set up, so it'd probably be better to adopt a library that supports reading/writing stores from outside of React. Like [Zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#readingwriting-state-and-reacting-to-changes-outside-of-components).